# STL algorithm function with reverse iterators doesn't work

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, iterator, reverse-iterator

I need to find minimum element in my array, but if amount of minimum elements more than 1, I need  to use the most right one.
Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> a(n);
    for (int& x : a)
        cin >> x;
    vector<int>::iterator it_min = min_element(a.rbegin(), a.rend());

}
```

It doesn't work. And it doesn't make sense to me why. Reverse_iterator basically provides all operators needed for correct execution of function. But apparently `min_element()` expecting only "normal" iterator is being given. Can I somehow bypass that? Ok, I can convert my reverse_iterator to iterator with `.base()` function member (`min_element(a.rbegin().base(), a.rend().base())`), but that doesn't resolve my problem since `operator+` is now going forward, not backwards. I could not think of anything sensible. Is there an elegant solution to this problem?

P.S. There's a solution to my problem with custom comparator and it works with normal iterators, but still I want to find out if there is a solution with reverse_iterators:

`vector<int>::iterator it_min = min_element(a.begin(), a.end(), [](int min, int b) { return min >= b; });`

UPD: After the answer, I understood that everything I said about min_element() is wrong. It can accept reverse_iterators and work with them correctly, but I was confused about why it requires conversion reverse_iterators to iterators, but it didn't required the `a.rbegin()` and `a.rend()` to convert to "normal" iterators. It required to convert the returning iterator itself.

Comment: `min_element(a.begin(), a.end(), [](int min, int b) { return min >= b; });` is ill-formed. `>=` is not valid for a *Compare*.

Comment: Also `min_element` does not distinguish "normal iterators" from "reverse iterators". It operates on the iterators that it's given

Comment: @Caleth why not valid? what's considered as valid? Can this comparator throw some kind of exception?

Comment: The requirement [*Compare*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) includes "For all `a`, `comp(a,a)==false`", which is not the case for a `>=` comparison. And it means your program has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing `reverse_iterator` to [`min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element), then it returns `reverse_iterator` too.

Change the code to

```
vector<int>::reverse_iterator it_min = min_element(a.rbegin(), a.rend());
```

Or

```
auto it_min = min_element(a.rbegin(), a.rend());
```

You can get the `vector<int>::iterator` from the returned `reverse_iterator` later by `it_min.base() - 1`.

Comment: Oh, I didnt think of that. Also we can use `min_element(a.rbegin(), a.rend()).base()` then.

Comment: @Learpcs Yes, if you want to get `vector<int>::iterator` back.

Comment: The reverse iterators have a surprising (to me) "off by one" effect, and the "normal" iterator to the minimum element is `it_min.base() - 1`.

Comment: actually that's one of the cases when usage of auto would be more harmful, because if used auto I woudn't even realized that `it_min` is now a reverse_iterator. And if I tried to do something with this iterator, I would ended up in much more confuse situation where my code doesn't work.

Comment: @molbdnilo Ohh, forgot it at all.

Comment: @Learpcs It depends, I like `auto` because of less typing..

Comment: @Learpcs Algorithm function templates could take any iterators including reverse iterators, and just process generally. They won't handle reverse iterators specially, e.g. taking reverse iterator and converting and returning *normal* iterators.

Comment: @Learpcs I like `auto` because I almost never care about the *exact* type of things, just what operations I want to do. For the result of `min_element`, that's often just dereferencing